# Microsoft Dynamics online: change field's data type

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

What are the steps for changing Field's (not custom) data type?
I go to Customizations -> Customize the System -> Entities -> Activity -> Fields -> Subject. I need to change Type from "Single Line of Text" to "Option set". How do I do that? 
I have Visual Studio 2012 and Microsoft Dynamics CRM SDK but I'm not experienced at it.

EDIT:
Do I need to retrieve FormXml from SystemForm entity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't change the type of the field after its creation (you can only change the properties, for example the minimum and maximum value for numeric types or the optionset entries).

If is a custom field you can delete and add again with the right type, if is a standard field the suggested way is to hide it from forms and views and create a new custom field instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Guido. But why Dynamics shows this link "For information about how to interact with entities and fields programmatically, see the Microsoft Dynamics CRM SDK" at the standard field customization page? Does it mean custom field? So it is not possible to retrieve FormXml from SystemForm entity, change it and update it?

Comment: your question is how to change the field type, the reply is that you can't change, the field needs to be deleted and created again (if it is a custom one). Manually or by SDK is indifferent. That message is a bit misleading

Comment: Regarding to your answer, can you please tell how to create new custom field for Activity Entity?

Comment: activity is a special entity, that contains the common fields shared by all the entities defined as activity (for example phone call, email, appointment, ...) so if you want to add a new optionset field inside appointment for example, you need to edit the appointment entity (and the same for phone call, fax, letter, ...)

Comment: Boo! I have to change the option set for a field but it won't let me.  Deleting is not an option because the field is in use all over the place! :-(

Comment: Actually, I can understand the need to create a new field.  My real problem is with the built-in Option Set called "a YES or NO boolean" but I didn't find out until later that the options are really ALLOWED and NOT ALLOWED!!!!