# Microsoft Dynamics online: set field's value from another field

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I learned that it is not possible to change Type of the field after it's creation (source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18871910/1600883). 
My goal is to display "Option Set" instead of "Single Line of Text" in the Appointment Entity Form, field called "Subject". So the solution should be to hide the "Subject" field and to add another custom field, which has "Option Set" as a Type. But the problem is that "Subject" is required, so I'm thinking about taking the value from "Option Set" and set it to "Subject". Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, just attach this javascript function to the `OnChange` optionset event.

```js
function optionsetOnChange() {
    var optionsetText = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_optionset").getText();
    Xrm.Page.getAttribute("subject").setValue(optionsetText);
}
```

and change `new_optionset` with the name of your optionset field.

Comment: Nice and very easiest solution but I would like to use plugin over javascript. Just to make sure that it won't break if javascript is disabled on browser.

Comment: yes, you are right. But if subject field is removed from form? Might be ok if hidden subject field is hidden.

Comment: subject can't be removed from the form (it's business required and has the lock icon beside). There are some checks that can be done to make sure it's all ok (for example set inside onsave event the submit mode if subject is read-only) but are outside the context of the question. And also using a plugin will be necessary some javascript, this because the field is required, so the form can't be saved (and the plugin called) because all the fields are filled.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible.

If you don't want Subject on form then remove it from form. Register a plugin on pre-operation  of Activity to populate the subject field with the value of OptionSet field.